# add acceleration to 'move_group->stop()' command

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when 'move_group->stop();' command triggered, or when i press 'Stop' button on 'RViz', the joint stops very suddenly.

how can i add acceleration to stop command ?
is that possible ?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400142/add-acceleration-to-%27move_group-%3Estop()%27-command/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> how can i add acceleration to stop command ? is that possible ?

No, that's not supported.

But, depending on which driver / controller you are using, you can make the stop smoother.

If you're using the [wiki/joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller) from `ros_control`, the `stop_trajectory_duration` parameter tells the controller how long (in seconds) the trajectory it uses to stop moving should be.

If you set that to a non-zero value, stops should become much less abrupt.

Note that a non-zero value could also have negative consequences, as it will also take longer to stop in cases where you would want the robot to stop immediately (for instance when trying to implement something like "touch sensing").

If you're not using a `ros_control`-compatible driver, you'd have to see whether your driver supports a similar setting.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2022-05-09**:
yes i use `JointTrajectoryController` and `stop_trajectory_duration` solved my problem. Thank you.

i will also add some protection later, for this reason i will search 'how to change `stop_trajectory_duration` programmatically.'

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-09**:\

> i will search 'how to change `stop_trajectory_duration` programmatically.'

that's not supported in the current implementation of the `JointTrajectoryController`. It's a parameter read only at initialisation time.

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2022-05-09**:
oh, thank you.
maybe, in emergency i will stop send new angles to joints, then sync angles between hardware and rviz, that may be solve the problem