# Execute move_group.stop() more smoothly

Tags: ros, rviz, move-group

After doing move_group.stop() my 6 axis robot arm stops suddenly, how can I stop it more smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of MoveIt's `stop()` function is to stop the arm, which may be sudden. As described in [this related question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/101658/add-acceleration-to-move-group-stop-command?rq=1), what you're looking to do here isn't supported by that command directly, although they do provide a workaround.

Because this is not how that command is intended to be used, I would recommend a different approach. Recall that the MoveIt planning API allows you to specify a goal, get back a plan, and then execute that plan. These plans are a series of joint states that the arm will attempt to interpolate between in constant time. As a result, if you add new joint states that interpolate between the existing joint states, you will slow the trajectory. If you only perform this interpolation to the last second of travel, only the last second will be slowed down.

Comment: thank you but how can i add new joint states during execution of already planned path

Comment: *During* execution? You can't. The goal of MoveIt is to find trajectories that move an arm from state A to state B, and then you can execute them as a static process. If you want more dynamic operation, you're probably using MoveIt incorrectly and should be looking at "servoing" or "jogging" the arm. @OmerANAR

Comment: So I can't change the speed of the robot during execution right ?

Comment: As I've said, MoveIt aims to provide you trajectories and then provide you with the ability to execute them. Changes during execution is really not how MoveIt works, and if you want this, you will need a different execution strategy: for example, manually "servoing" or "jogging" the arm.

Comment: but [stop_trajectory_duration](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller) adding some acceleration after calling 'stop' function,Thus, the robot arm can stop more smoothly. I need to write a function that can do the work of this parameter, using cpp.

Comment: Yes, we agree: MoveIt is not the tool for the job you require, you will need to write custom code that can perform joint-level velocity or torque control in real time.